# Will angular push my object out of scope, or merge the object with my provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not exactly sure how to word my question, but my concern involves an object I have called xyzApi.  I define this object outside of my angular code and it contains some classes and utility methods etc that I want to be available to the rest of my api.

It looks like this (short version):

```
var xyzApi = xyzApi || {
    entities : new function () {
        this.oAuthToken = function (token, expires, type) {
            this.token = token;
            this.expires = expires;
            this.type = type;
            this.toString = function () {
                if (this.token != null)
                    return this.type + ' ' + this.token;
                return null;
            };
        };
    }
};
```

Now, my angular service layer creates a provider that is also called xyzApi.  It looks something like this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('xyzDataWebServices').provider('xyzApi', function () {
        var baseUrl;
        this.setBaseUrl = function (value) {
            baseUrl = value;
        };
        this.$get = ['$log', 'baseRequest', 'xyzApiContext', 'xyzApiAuthentication', 'xyzApiLibrary', function xyzApiFactory($log, baseRequest, xyzApiContext, xyzApiAuthenication, xyzApiLibrary) {
            baseRequest.setServiceUrl(baseUrl);
            var factory = {
                context: xyzApiContext,
                authentication: xyzApiAuthenication,
                library: xyzApiLibrary
            }
            return factory;
        }];
    });
})();
```

Now when code uses the provider, I want my original object, to be merged onto the provider as if it were part of it.

Will that happen automatically, or will being in scope of a controller using the provider causes the original object to not be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood it correctly you could merge your `factory` and your `xyzApi` inside your provider.

I think that doesn't happen automatically. But if you're adding `angular.merge(factory, xyzApi);` in your provider it should work like you want it.

`angular.merge()` is working with Angular 1.4 or later. `angular.extend()` would probably also work but deep merging is then not happening.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/9bz4Lwxa/).

It just shows the merge of those two objects.

```js
var xyzApi = xyzApi || {
 sayHello: function() {
   return "hey there\n";
  }
};

angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('MainController', MainController)
  .provider('xyzApi', function XyzApiProvider() {
  
  this.$get = function() {
  
   var xyzApiFactory = {
      otherFunction: function() {
        //$log.log('other function called');
        return 'other function \n';
      }
   };
    //console.log(xyzApiFactory, xyzApi);
    angular.merge(xyzApiFactory, xyzApi);
    return xyzApiFactory;
  };
});


function MainController(xyzApi) {
 var vm = this;
  vm.test = '';
  
 vm.sayHello = function() {
   vm.test += xyzApi.sayHello() + xyzApi.otherFunction();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
<pre>{{mainCtrl.test}}</pre>
  <button ng-click="mainCtrl.sayHello()">
  say hello!!
  </button>
</div>
```